# Getting errors trying to connect to my sites FTP account from Filezilla

Tags: ftp, cpanel, filezilla

I'm getting the following error when I try to connect to my FTP account in Filezilla using the given cPanel FTP configuration. I've gone ahead and double checked it and tried entering it manually but I continue to get the same error.

`Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known".`

Everything I find tells me that something may be wrong in how I'm entering something but I'm sure that I am not. I'm unable to figure out this and I've worked with Filezilla and connecting to many other FTP accounts using the FTP configs in cPanel successfully.

Example FTP settings:

`Host: ftp.address.com`

`Protocol: FTP`

`Encryption: Use explicit FTP over TLS if available`

`Logon Type: Normal`

`User: user@address.com`

`Password: ************`

I've triple-checked the password and tried resetting it a few times in the cPanel.

I've tried removing the `ftp.` part in front of the host name to someone elses suggestions but I then get the following error:

`Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".`

I'm at a lost and I can't figure out how to connect to my site. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your FTP server is actually working or listening. Connection refused by the server means that FTP server is not up and running. You can try to do a `telnet ftp-server-ip-address 21` and see if you are able to connect or not.

Issue via ssh:
 `systemctl restart pure-ftpd` and then `systemctl status pure-ftpd` to see if your ftp server is actually started. Additionally you can issue:

`nestat -tunlp` and check the list to see if you see the ftp service listening to the port 21. You should see an entry like this one:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8788/pure-ftpd (SER
```

You can restart the ftp server from WHM as well

Answer (score 0):

for connecting to Cpanel through filezilla ftp client, i think this is how you should set the required things:

```
host: address.com
```

(no need to add ftp in the beginning)

```
User: user@address.com

Password: ************
```

**Note that this user should be active in FTP Account.**